# Aggregating a Subset

Tags: r, aggregate

```
aggregate(value ~ Vertical+ OLorPL, mdata,sum,na.rm=TRUE)
```

The above code works, but it includes a column "Horizontal" in the sum.  I would like to aggregate all records, summing value, but excluding the records where mdata$Horizontal == "xyz"

Answer (score 1):

I hope you would have noticed that the `aggregate` function *does* have a `subset` argument.

Compare:

No subsetting from the "mtcars" dataset.

```
aggregate(mpg ~ cyl + gear, mtcars, mean)
#   cyl gear    mpg
# 1   4    3 21.500
# 2   6    3 19.750
# 3   8    3 15.050
# 4   4    4 26.925
# 5   6    4 19.750
# 6   4    5 28.200
# 7   6    5 19.700
# 8   8    5 15.400
```

Subsetting to drop any rows where "cyl" and "gear" are equal to 4:

```
aggregate(mpg ~ cyl + gear, mtcars, mean, 
          subset=c(!cyl %in% 4 & !gear %in% 4))
#   cyl gear   mpg
# 1   6    3 19.75
# 2   8    3 15.05
# 3   6    5 19.70
# 4   8    5 15.40
```

This should give you the same result as @MatthewLundberg's approach, which would look like this:

```
aggregate(mpg ~ cyl + gear, 
          mtcars[!mtcars$cyl %in% 4 & !mtcars$gear %in% 4, ], 
          mean)
```

Comment: In fact, I had not noticed this.  Do you know of any gotcha's for this option?

Comment: @MatthewLundberg, Don't know of any myself--I haven't looked at the code to `stats:::aggregate.formula` to see how it is implemented though.

Answer (score 0):

Simply exclude these records from `data`:

```
aggregate(value ~ Vertical+ OLorPL, mdata[mdata$Horizontal != 'xyz',],sum,na.rm=TRUE)
```